# spark cassandra connector write timeout when when tuning write conf

Tags: performance, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have noticed a very low throughput in our pipeline when inserting data from spark to cassandra (less than 1 MB/s per core).
When trying to tune write conf (`spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes`, `spark.cassandra.output.batch.grouping.key` and `spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.rows`) I am getting quickly a write timeout.

My questions:

- Is it recommended/normal to increase the cassandra write timeout when writing data in batch (via spark)?
- Is it possible to increase it just for spark workloads? or just for batch writes?
- The default value for `spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.bytes` is 1024, I find that too low as a default value, I guess in most times that would correspond to 1 or 2 rows, am I missing something ?

I am using spark-cassandra-connector 2.4.3

Comment: what are you setting for `spark.cassandra.output.batch.grouping.key` ?

Comment: I tried to disable batching and set the max throughput by core (`output.throughput_mb_per_sec`) to 1Mb/s because I dont have many rows by cassandra partition in my dataset. Any way, I am getting the timeout even when increasing only `spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes` from 5 to 25 (+ default values for other parameters)

Comment: this change most probably overloaded the coordinator nodes - check the Cassandra logs on other side... You need to take into account that by default Spark writes with consistency level `TWO`...

Comment: We have probably something  to improve in cassandra side. My question is, is it common to have the same write timeout when writing in batch with spark and with other services. I find it logical to increase the default write timeout in cassandra for spark workloads but I wanted to have other confirmations/rex to see if its a good practice

Comment: write timeout when using batch usually comes when you're using batches with update to multiple partitions, Spark by default group by partition that is translated into  single mutation in Cassandra, and it's fast because of that

Comment: Ok I see, thank you for your feedback!